# Capybara ends session on every redirekt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

whenever I tell capybara to click on a link it immediately terminates the session I am in and brings me to the login screen. Obviously when browsing normal everything works fine.

this is my rspec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'webdrivers'

RSpec.describe "Searches", driver: :selenium_firefox, js: true, type: :system do
  before do
    driven_by(:rack_test)
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    driven_by :selenium_firefox
  end

  it "populate movie form" do
    visit search_path
    find('#home_path').click
    sleep(3)
  end
end
```

in spec_helper.rb I have set this:

```
  Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3002"
  Capybara.server_host = "localhost"
  Capybara.server_port = "3002"
```

and in rails_helper. rb: `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false`

I have also gotten the href through capybara which is correct `http://localhost:3002/search`

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `driven_by` twice in your before block makes no sense.  Each driver uses its own session so it's no surprise you're having session issues.  Get rid of both `driven_by` calls in the before block and see what happens.

There's also no need to set `app_host` if you're letting Capybara run the application under test, which it appears you are since you're setting server_host and server_port.